# Computed value does not recognize prop object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

That I want to do is create a computed value in order to use on my view so as this [Documentation](https://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-ultimate-guide) I try:

I have a component where I send an array object as:

```
const tabs = ref([
      {
        imageSrc: '/programs/test1.png',
         ....
      },
```

And in other component I receive it as :

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ProgramModal',

  props: {
    tabs: {
      type: Array as PropType<Array<any>>,
      required: true,
    },
  },


  computed: {
    img() {
      return `./images/modal/${encodeURIComponent(this.tabs.imageSrc)}.png`
    },
  },

})
```

As you can see I have a computed value that is throwing two errors, one in `img` and the other in `this.tabs.imageSrc`:

First error:

> img implicitly has return type any because it does not have a return
> type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its
> return expression

Second error:

> Property tabs does not exist on type  { img(): any; }

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: It says what's wrong, "it does not have a return type annotation". Don't use options API with TS, composition API specifically was designed to be more type-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. TypeScript support for the Options API has a [known limitation that requires annotating return types on `computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Annotating-Return-Types):

   > Because of the circular nature of Vue’s declaration files, TypeScript may have difficulties inferring the types of certain methods. For this reason, you may need to annotate the return type on methods like `render` and those in `computed`.

   So you should annotate the return type of `img()`:

   ```js
   img(): string {
             
     return `...`
   }
   ```

   Without fixing this error, type inference for the component instance will be *broken*, leading to the error you observed: `Property tabs does not exist on type { img(): any; }`.
2. As pointed out in a deleted answer here, `this.tabs` is an array, but your computed prop tries to read `imageSrc` directly from the array when it really should be from an *array element*. To read the first array element's `imageSrc`, use square brackets with the zero index (`this.tabs[0].imageSrc`):

   ```js
   return `./images/modal/${encodeURIComponent(this.tabs[0].imageSrc)}.png`
   ```

Your code should look similar to this:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    img(): string {
      return `./images/modal/${encodeURIComponent(this.tabs[0].imageSrc)}.png`
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Awesome! no errors but how can I access it on HTML? I try with: `<img src="img" />` but it just throws `src: "img"` instead the literal string route

Comment: That binding should be: `v-bind:src="img"` or shorthand: `:src="img"`